# How to change the color of a NSToolbarItem's label

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I'd like to change the color of all of my `NSToolbarItem`'s labels.

I need to set it to white because it suits better to the background color of my `NSWindow`, but it defaults to black and I haven't found a way to change it neither in Interface Builder nor directly by code (`NSToolbarItem` implements `setLabel`, but it just sets the text string).

If possible, I'd like to avoid:

- Replacing the whole `NSToolbar` by a custom `NSView`. Would feel like reinventing the wheel to me.
- Having to create custom `NSView`s inside `NSToolbarItem`. It would imply having to leave blank all of its labels and adding the white-colored label inside the custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I solved it by:

- Using custom views inside `NSToolbarItem`s containing both a button and a label.
- Displaying icon only instead of icon + label in `NSToolbar` in order to hide the default label.

I had to deal with another problem related to a bug with Interface Builder: the custom view was not showing at all. I was able to fix it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009791/739556).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using [NSMutableAttributeString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableAttributedString).
For example:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib{
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.label];
NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, title.length);
[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:titleRange];
[self setLabel:title]; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to subclass NSBarButtonItem and override the drawRect method for that. Otherwise it will use `[NSColor controlTextColor]` or `[NSColor disabledControlTextColor]`.

Comment: Started trying what you suggested and NSBarButtonItem class doesn't exist in AppKit. Also, I was asking for NSToolbarItem, which inherits from NSObject so there's no drawRect method.